# Studying the Riemann integrability of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given this set of inequalities : $2^{f(x)}\leq x \leq 2^{f(x)+1}$ , we're asked to study the Riemann integrability of this function , where  $x\in [1,1995]$ . No further details are offered . Any idea on how to approach this ? I couldn't even think of a way to start .

Comment: Ok, the function is bounded on the given interval. But don't you have any information about its regularity? Is it continuous?

Comment: That's my problem as well ,I think that simply assuming that the function is continuous is a major leap, but these are absolutely all the details we've been given.In conditions such as these, I believe we're supposed to consider the function continuous and concentrate on the proof.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then it is automatically integrable. It is a strange exercise...

Comment: Let's just say that my math teacher isn't the most rigorous person in the field, so he might've slipped some 'details' when creating this particular problem.Nonetheless, I was taken aback when I first saw this exercise and I asked him to further define his notion of "integrability" .The only answer I got is that all I need to know is already there on paper.

Comment: You can't say much.  All you have is that $f(x) \in [\log_2 x - 1, \log_2 x]$.  So if the Riemann integral exists, it'll be between the integrals of those bounds.  If $f(x)$ is continuous, then it must be Riemann integrable; if it's not continuous, the integral need not exist at all.

Comment: Use the Dirichlet function (index function of the irrationals) and shift it to construct a counter example.